# Why I have to convert bytes from BytesIO then convert back to BytesIO so it can be read as PDF file response?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, pypdf

I use `PyPDF4` to merge pdf files, then I use the merged pdf as a `HttpResponse`.
I use `BytesIO` to get the result from `PdfFileMerger`.

I got it working using this code

```
def mergePDF(listOfPDFFile):
    merger = PdfFileMerger()
    for file in listOfPDFFile:
        merger.append(PdfFileReader(file))
    _byteIo = BytesIO()
    merger.write(_byteIo)
    return _byteIo.getvalue()
```

Then when I use the method in `APIView` to return the merged pdf as a `HttpResponse`

```
class DocumentBundlePDFView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        '''
         here goes a process to assign list of document to documentList
        '''
        pdfBytes = mergePDF(documentList)
        pdfFile = io.BytesIO(pdfBytes)
        response = HttpResponse(FileWrapper(pdfFile), content_type='application/pdf')
        return response
```

But, why I have to create `BytesIO` object twice to get it working?
Initially I return the `_byteIO` instance then directly pass the instance to `FileWrapper` but it output 0Kb file.

So I convert the `_byteIO` instance to `bytes` then create another `BytesIO` instance in APIView to get it working.

How can I simplify the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `mergePDF` function, instead of returning

```
return _byteIo.getvalue()
```

Do something to the effect of

```
_byteIo.seek(0)
return _byteIo
```

> Initially I return the _byteIO instance then directly pass the
>   instance to FileWrapper but it output 0Kb file.

The problem is when you write to the file-like object, the cursor is set to the last byte. Just move it back to the beginning, or else it will be like reading from an empty file.